# Python Telegram Bot is not Ideling on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, python-telegram-bot

I am using heroku to deploy my telegram bot. I am using free dynos. So, to save dyno hours I want my app to go idle after 30 mins of inactivity which it should.

https://www.heroku.com/dynos

But, my app get random GET requests after 25mins or so. So, my app never goes to idle.

Note:
My app is not yet on production so I cannot figure out why I am getting ping every 25min.

here is my code:

```
import telegram.ext
import bot
from config import TOKEN,PORT

def start(update,context):
    id = update.message.chat.id
    if(id == (hidden) or id == (hidden)):
        update.message.reply_text("Welcome! to Football Story Bot")
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("""
            We have detected unusual request from your device.
You have been banned from the service until further notice,
        """)

def help(update,context):
    id = update.message.chat.id
    if(id == (hidden) or id == (hidden)):
        update.message.reply_text("""
        The following commands are available:
        /start -> Welcome Message
        /help -> This Message
        /streams -> list of matches
        """)
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("""
            We have detected unusual request from your device.
You have been banned from the service until further notice,
        """)


def streams(update,context):
    id = update.message.chat.id
    if(id == (hidden) or id == (hidden)):
        update.message.reply_text("Searching for available matches")
        all_matches_name_list = bot.all_matches_name()
        link_str=''
        if(all_matches_name_list==None):
            update.message.reply_text("We are experiencing problem.Try again later, if problem persists then contact admin")
            return None
        for links in all_matches_name_list:
            link_str+=links+'\n'
        update.message.reply_text(link_str)
        update.message.reply_text("End Of Detected Matches")
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("""
            We have detected unusual request from your device.
You have been banned from the service until further notice,
        """)

def handle_message(update,context):
    id = update.message.chat.id
    if(id == (hidden) or id == (hidden)):
        update.message.reply_text("Searching for available streams")
        link_str=''
        sending_message=''
        for chars in update.message.text:
            if(chars=='@'):
                break
            sending_message+=chars
        individual_link = bot.selected_match(bot.all_matches_name(),sending_message)
        if(individual_link==None):
            update.message.reply_text("We are experiencing problem.Try again later, if problem persists then contact admin hai tw")
            return None
        if(len(individual_link)==0):
            update.message.reply_text("No links found. Links are updated 30min before match. If link is not found till Kick Off then contact admin")
            return None
        for links in individual_link:
            link_str+=links+'\n\n'
        update.message.reply_text(link_str)
        update.message.reply_text("End Of Streaming Links")
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("""
            We have detected unusual request from your device.
You have been banned from the service until further notice,
        """)

updater = telegram.ext.Updater(TOKEN,use_context=True)

disp = updater.dispatcher

disp.add_handler(telegram.ext.CommandHandler("start",start))
disp.add_handler(telegram.ext.CommandHandler("help",help))
disp.add_handler(telegram.ext.CommandHandler("streams",streams))
disp.add_handler(telegram.ext.MessageHandler(telegram.ext.Filters.command,handle_message))
updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0",
                      port=PORT,
                      url_path=TOKEN,
                      webhook_url="(my app link)" + TOKEN)
updater.idle()
```

Comment: Why not just start a timer and idle manually when the time is up? Seems like the simplest way to overcome this.

Comment: @Skully But it should start again after it recieves a request

Comment: Then after the timer is up and you go idle, whenever a request is received you can simply check to see if you went idle because of 30 minutes having elapsed; and if that is the case, start it up again.